# opencv python is faster than c++?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, time

I am trying to time the houghcircle in python and c++ to see if c++ gives edge over processing time (intuitively it should!)

#### Versions

- python: 3.6.4
- gcc compiler: gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609
- cmake : 3.5.1
- opencv : 3.4.1

> I actually installed opencv using anaconda. Surprisingly c++ version
>   also worked

The image I am using is given here:
[image]

## Python code

```
import cv2
import time
import sys

def hough_transform(src,dp,minDist,param1=100,param2=100,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(src,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    start_time = time.time()
    circles=cv2.HoughCircles(gray,
                             cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,
                             dp = dp,
                             minDist = minDist,
                             param1=param1,
                             param2=param2,
                             minRadius=minRadius,
                             maxRadius=maxRadius)
    end_time = time.time()
    print("Time taken for hough circle transform is : {}".format(end_time-start_time))
    # if circles is not None:
    #         circles = circles.reshape(circles.shape[1],circles.shape[2])
    # else:
    #     raise ValueError("ERROR!!!!!! circle not detected try tweaking the parameters or the min and max radius")
    #
    # a = input("enter 1 to visualize")
    # if int(a) == 1 :
    #     for circle in circles:
    #         center = (circle[0],circle[1])
    #         radius = circle[2]
    #         cv2.circle(src, center, radius, (255,0,0), 5)
    #
    #     cv2.namedWindow("Hough circle",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    #     cv2.imshow("Hough circle",src)
    #     cv2.waitKey(0)
    #     cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    #
    #
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        raise ValueError("usage: python hough_circle.py <path to image>")
    image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    hough_transform(image,1.7,100,50,30,690,700)
```

## C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void hough_transform(Mat src, double dp, double minDist, double param1=100, double param2=100, int minRadius=0, int maxRadius=0 )
{
  Mat gray;
  cvtColor( src, gray, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
  vector<Vec3f> circles;
  int start_time = clock();
  HoughCircles( gray, circles, HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDist, param1, param2, minRadius, maxRadius);
  int end_time = clock();
  cout<<"Time taken hough circle transform: "<<(end_time-start_time)/double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC)<<endl;
  // cout<<"Enter 1 to visualize the image";
  // int vis;
  // cin>>vis;
  // if (vis == 1)
  // {
  //   for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
  //   {
  //       Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
  //       int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
  //       circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(255,0,0), 5);
  //   }
  //   namedWindow( "Hough Circle", WINDOW_NORMAL);
  //   imshow( "Hough Circle", src);
  //   waitKey(0);
  //   destroyAllWindows();
  // }
  return;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if( argc != 2 ){
    cout<<"Usage hough_circle <path to image.jpg>";
    return -1;
  }
  Mat image;
  image = imread(argv[1]);
  cvtColor(image,image,COLOR_BGR2RGB);
  hough_transform(image,1.7,100,50,30,690,700);
  return 0;
}
```

I was hoping for C++ hough transform to ace python but what happened was actually opposite.

## Python result:

[image]

## C++ result:

[image]

Even though C++ ran the complete program ~2X faster it is very slow in hough transform. Why is it so? This is very counter intuitive. What am I missing here?

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Please increase the test-case, so it runs for, at least, several seconds. Such small deviations prove nothing, as they are common between executions, due to normal operation of the computer. Side note: Please copy-paste the text from the terminal, instead of providing pictures of text.

Comment: Do you use compiler flags like -O1  -O2  -O3  or -Ofast?

Comment: No I don't use any flags. This is my cmake file: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( hough )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( hoigh_circle_test hough_circle_test.cpp )
target_link_libraries( hough_circle_test ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't expect any difference between the two at all to be honest.  The python library more than likely is a wrapper around the C++ library; meaning that once they get into the core of the opencv they will have identical performance if compiled with the same optimisation flags.

The only slight slowdown I'd *EXPECT* is python getting to that point; and with so little python code actually there; the difference is unlikely to be measureable.  The fact that you're seeing it the other way around I don't think proves anything as you're performing a single test; and getting a difference of 0.2s which could trivially be the difference in just the hard disk seeking to the file to process.

Comment: so you saying it doesn't matter if the code is in python or cpp as long as am using opencv? I am actually comparing cpp and python coz speed is my atmost priority. I have all my code in python. (Most of them have very little python code ) it is direct usage of opencv functions. So converting them to cpp will not have significant speed advantage?

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji not the opencv bits, because they'll switch back to the cpp implementation library very quickly  (They want it to be fast in python too!).  How you process the results may be faster in c++ than in python; but nothing's stopping you putting your processing of the results in c++ in a module if it's slow.  (Just make sure that you have a module that abstracts that chunk away; and then you'll not have to re-write everything if you try that route)

Comment: If what you are saying is true. The time taken to compute Hough transform should be almost same. In python it is atleast 3times faster. According to my code, the time taken for Hough transform is independent of reading the file

Comment: @AbhijitBalaji you also say that you've not compiled with any optimisation flags; and you'll see I state "identical performance if compiled with the same optimisation flags." - I'd be surprised that opencv would be released for python without optimisation.

Comment: I don't quite understand, what are these optimization flags?

Comment: [related](https://www.quora.com/When-should-you-use-the-different-GCC-optimization-flags-e-g-O2-I-saw-that-OpenCV-uses-the-O2-optimization-instead-of-O3-on-32-bit-Linux-What-are-the-pros-cons-of-each-optimization-level) I'm not going to do more than that because it's a question in it's own right

Answer (score 3):

I was actually comparing 2 different times. Namely wall and CPU. 
In Linux, in C++ clock() gives CPU time and in Windows it gives wall time. So when I changed my python code to time.clock() Both gave same results. [image]

As explained by @UKMonkey, The time to calculate hough in python and C++ did not have any difference at all. But, running the entire program in c++ was almost 2.5 times faster (looped 100 times).Hands down to C++ :P.